# How to spawn a terminal?

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I can't find an example of pexpect spawning a Linux terminal. `child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')` does nothing and the script just insta-closes.

This is probably a really stupid question, sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of examples in the [documentation](http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/#doc).

`child = pexpect.spawn('/bin/bash')` will spawn a new child, but if you don't interact with it, you won't see anything, as the input and output are handled by pexpect. And if you don't have anything else in your script, the child will be destroyed when your interpreter exits.

Pexpect doesn't open any visible terminal, the child is running entirely in the background (unless you call `child.interact()`).

Comment: Yeah I already figured it out, but thanks anyway. Was just really confused because nothing came up and interact gave me an error.